# Mount USB devices in Arch Linux

Tags: usb, arch-linux, automount, usb-storage

I recently installed Arch on my computer and now I would like to read data from USB devices (i.e. flash drives, SD cards, etc.) but I don't know how to. I know that using Gnome or KDE will do this for me automatically but I am only using Openbox for my installation so I don't know where to start.

I read from the Arch Wiki that [Udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev) handles this but I don't know how to use it (or find it for that matter). I also checked and `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is empty so I doubt that my USB devices are mounted automatically. I want to:

1. Know where these devices are being (or are going to be) mounted
2. Know how to check if these devices are mounted
3. Know how to mount them if these devices are not mounted
4. Know how to automatically mount them once I insert them into the USB slot

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_1,2. Just type `mount` into the terminal.

_3. After you attach a usb drive, you may want too look `dmesg | tail`. The last few lines should contain information about the attached drive, I mean you can find out which `/dev/sd?` was assigned to your drive. Then you create a directory in which you want the drive mounted, with `mkdir NAME_OF_DIR` and mount the drive in it by `mount YOUR_FLASH YOUR_DIRECTORY`. Also, don't forget that if you read `/dev/sde` in `dmesg`, you should write `mount /dev/sde1 /media/myflash1`, where `sde1` stands for the first partition on the drive sde.

_4. I suggest reading [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices) for this one.

Comment: Thanks for your tip on using `dmesg | tail`, I now know what the device name (e.g. `sdb`) is so I'd know how to mount them manually. As for automounting, I copied the sample rule in the link you gave but still it isn't mounted (or is it because I am logged in as a user and not root?)

Comment: I logged in as `root` and stuck my flash disk to the USB drive and it still wasn't automounted to `/media` as per the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices). Any ideas?